# How to Compare Rough Time Strings in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, time

Actually I want to Compare Time Duration Strings.

```
var str1 = "2 Hours 15 Minutes"; //possible value "2 Hr 15 Min"
var str2 = "3 Hours 9 Minutes"; //possible value "3 Hr 9 Min"
if(str1 > str2) ???
```

Comment: When you say 'rough' does that mean this won't always be the exact format?

Comment: actually i want a universal solution with rough(almost 2,3 formats) parameters @MarkMeyer

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to parse the string, and convert it to some common value (minutes in my code), then compare the numbers.

Since your strings have a standard structure, you can use a simple regular expression with [`String.match()`](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=strng%20match&oq=strng%20match&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1533j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) to extract the numbers. Multiply the 1st number by 60, and add the second number, to get the number of minutes.

```js
function parseTimeString(str) {
  var hours = str.match(/\d+(?=\s+(Hours|Hr))/g) || [0];
  var min = str.match(/\d+(?=\s+Min)/g) || [0];
  return +hours[0] * 60 + +min[0];
}

function compareTimeStrings(str1, str2) {
  return parseTimeString(str1) > parseTimeString(str2);
}

var str1 = "2 Hours 15 Minutes"; //possible value "2 Hr 15 Min"
var str2 = "3 Hours 9 Minutes"; //possible value "3 Hr 9 Min"

console.log(compareTimeStrings(str1, str2));

// parseTimeString examples
console.log(parseTimeString(''));
console.log(parseTimeString('2 Hours')); // 120
console.log(parseTimeString('5 Minues')); // 5
console.log(parseTimeString('5 Minutes 2 Hours')); // 125
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: what if one of the variable contains only '2 Hours' ?

Comment: Can your string be only hours or only minutes? Your question should include all possible formats.

Comment: I've updated the code to extract hours and minutes separately. See added examples.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a general solution, you'll need to decide what level of generalization you need to support. This can range from simple regex parsing to something better suited to a neural network. Assuming the former, a simpler generalization would be to support and strings formatted as `number units` with known units. You can make a simple lookup that gives the unit multiple in seconds. To go a step further you could even have a list of conjunctions that will be stripped like `and` or `plus`:

```js
const units = {
  'seconds': 1,
  'minutes': 60,
  'hours': 3600,
  'hr': 3600,
  'min': 60,
  'sec': 1,
  'days': 86400

  // etc...
}
const stopwords = /and|plus|\+/gi // will be replaced with space

function gteSeconds(str)  {
  let times = str
      .replace(stopwords, ' ')
      .match(/\d+\s+\w+/g).map(t => t.split(/\s+/))
      
  return times.reduce((total, [time, unit]) => total + time * units[unit.toLowerCase()]
  , 0)
}
console.log(gteSeconds('3 Hours 9 Minutes'))
console.log(gteSeconds('20 seconds'))
console.log(gteSeconds('20 seconds 2 minutes'))
console.log(gteSeconds('1 Hr and 2 sec'))
console.log(gteSeconds('20 sec + 2 sec'))
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not a trivial problem, if you want to solve it properly!

I'd suggest to use one of the libraries that allow for easy parsing of dates and have comparison functions.

The first one that comes to my mind is `moment.js` that has an amazing way of comparing durations - `moment-duration`.

Moment Duration must be, however, built with following syntax, for example:

```
let duration = moment.duration(1, 'minutes);
```

(more here: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/creating/)

You'd have to split your duration strings into parts, consisting of number and duration unit:

```
let str1 = '2 Hours 15 Minutes';
let durationStrings = str1.match(/\d+ [a-zA-Z]+/g);
```

After that step, you'll have array of strings of something like that:

```
['2 hours', '15 minutes'];
```

After that, we need to split the strings for the second time, to build proper duration. Then, we'll use our values for building final duration:

```
// Create empty duration first...
let duration = moment.duration();

durationStrings.forEach((durationString) => {
  let durationArguments = durationString.split(' '); // We just use space as delimiter

  if (durationArguments.length === 2) {
    duration.add(Number(durationArguments[0]), durationArguments[1]);
  }
});

console.log(duration);
```

If you check final duration object, it should contain proper duration after iterations.

Let's now wrap it into function called `convertToDuration(string)`.

Note two things:

- We assume that each `durationString` contains Number, then space, then duration expression
- We have to convert `string` to `number` in the loop, as `moment-duration` assumes that the first argument is number

Now, the only thing to do is to build both durations as above and compare them, using e.g:

```
let duration1 = convertToDuration(str1);
let duration2 = convertToDuration(str2);

// If duration subtraction is negative, first one is smaller!
let subtractionResult = duration1.subtract(duration2).as('milliseconds');

if (subtractionResult < 0) {
  // Your logic here
}
```

You can find my solution here:
https://jsbin.com/berijuduza